# Flyway and H2: why are the schema_version table and columns lower-case and case-sensitive?

Tags: h2, flyway

More info:

http://www.h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/constant/DbSettings.html#DATABASE_TO_UPPER

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/h2-database/B1zEC0V6m34

It looks like all upper case is the default for H2.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The schema_version table name is case-sensitive due to the quotes in the creation script. This  allows for characters not supported in identifiers otherwise. You can configure flyway.table to an uppercase value if you wish.

The columns inside the table are internal to Flyway and not meant as a public API. They are private and therefore can change from one Flyway version to the next. Flyway will always ensure these changes are automatic with no manual effort for you.

Comment: Ah I wasn't even aware that quotes in sql scripts can have such an effect. databases have a surprise in store for me every single day. Anyway I'm glad this mystery is cleared up. I was mainly bugged by the inconsistency, and because I didn't understand how it was possible. Btw, before asking this question I actually did try flyway.setTable("SCHEMA_VERSION")...

Comment: This can be incredibly frustrating when configuring new setups. An optional property to disable the quoting would be most welcome!

Comment: @corsiKa, I could not agree more.

Answer (score 0):

You enclose the table name in "double quotes" to ensure the actual table created does not suffer from an toUpperCase translation - a feature that is supported in some dbs by configuration.

Enclosing the "table" in quotes ensures the table created is exactly as requested.